# TypeError: promises[i].done is not a function

Tags: angularjs

I am returning an $http.get object from a service to a controller.

function in the geturl service -

```
    this.fetch = function(index){
      var url = some_url;
      return $http.get(url,{timeout:8000});
    };
```

In the controller I have --

```
    var request = geturl.fetch(0);
    request.success(function(data,status,headers,config){
        // some logic
    }).error(function(data,status,headers,config){
        // some logic
    });

    $scope.promise.push(request); // $scope.promise is an array which contains all the promises

    whenAll($scope.promise).done(function(){
    });
```

function whenAll -

```
    function whenAll(promises) {
    var i, data = [],
    dfd = $.Deferred();
    for (i = 0; i < promises.length; i++) {
        promises[i].done(function(newData) {
            // something
        }).fail(function() {
          //something
        });
    }
    return dfd.promise();
    }
```

I am getting the following error - 
TypeError: promises[i].done is not a function

Answer (score 2):

If you want to execute something when all your promises resolve...

...you should take a look at $q.all()

Enjoy!

Answer (score 0):

This is not the angular way I should say you must use $q service for it.:-

```
   $q.all([Your array]).then(function(values) {
        //Your code
    });
```

Service:-

```
this.fetch = function(index){
    var url = some_url;
    var def = $q.defer();
    $http.get(url,{timeout:8000}).success(function(data) {
             def.resolve(data);
            })
            .error(function() {
                def.reject("Failed to get albums");
            });
        return def.promise;;
};
```

Controller:-

```
var promises = [];
var promise1 = geturl.fetch(0);
var promise2 = geturl.fetch(1);
promises.push(promise1);
promises.push(promise2);  
 $q.all(promises).then(function(results){

});
```

Hope it help :)